# Show result instead of X with incomplete mapping in vim

Tags: vim, keymapping

In my file at `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex/insert.vim` I have the following mappings

```
; <Nul> is ctrl-space
imap <Nul> \,
imap <Nul><Nul> ~
imap <Nul><Nul><Nul> \enspace
imap <Nul><Nul><Nul><Nul> \quad
imap <Nul><Nul><Nul><Nul><Nul> \qquad
```

This allows me to insert spaces of different width by pressing ctrl-space, with each press making the whitespace longer. When I type the first ctrl-space, I get an `X` and it waits for me to see if I wanted to input more ctrl-spaces or if I'm done.

I would like to know if there's a way to show what the space will be, either input it directly to the buffer and change it if it's pressed again, or put it in the status bar until I'm done.

A way I think this could be possible was to check if the chars before the cursor are `\,` and if they are replace it with the next space, and if it's not, check the rest of the spaces I can input and finally input a `\,` if none of the spaces are there. I just don't know how to accomplish such a keymap.

Comment: The issue is that vim has to wait to see if you're going to press more <Nul>'s. That happens at a lower level than what you're aiming for.

Comment: @JoeSewell what I was thinking might be possible bind only a single <Nul> to a function which cycles through them and edits the buffer directly. However I don't know how or if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your current map solution is based on the mapping timeout. Until that happens, Vim is waiting for more input, and nothing has been inserted yet. In order to later revise what got inserted, you need to completely replace the approach.

This could be implemented with `:map <expr> <Nul>`, checking what's before the cursor, and then returning `<BS>` characters to wipe that followed by the replacing text.

With the [mjbrownie/swapit](https://github.com/mjbrownie/swapit) plugin, you'll get that "toggling through alternatives" functionality (using `<C-a>` / `<C-x>`) for free: Just put the following into `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex/swapit.vim`:

```
SwapList spaces \, ~ \enspace \quad \qqad
```

You can keep your original `<Nul>` mappings to quickly insert when you know what you want (or for the initial insert), and use swapit only to revise later on.